# Maximum Number of Tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

What is the maximum number of tables that MySQL can handle?

Comment: For docs, please see [Limits on Number of Databases and Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/database-count-limit.html) and similar. E.g. `InnoDB` permits up to 4 billion tables (and I must admit if that is US-Billions or not I can't say). For a professional commentary: [Bill Karwin on "Is there a maximum number of tables a MySQL database can have?"](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-maximum-number-of-tables-a-MySQL-database-can-have)

Comment: Here is one such use case: I am importing all our company's Google Sheets into database tables, they each could be structured differently because Google Sheets does not have schema controls and Microsoft hasn't released Access for the web.

Answer (score 30):

The fact that you are asking this question is probably an indicator that you are not taking a best practice approach to your problem.

You may want to explain why you need to create many tables, in order to see if you will receive better suggestions on how to tackle this issue.

However, there are no server limits on the number of tables in a MySQL database, but since each MyISAM table has associated files, then any OS limits on the number of files allowed will have an effect. InnoDB tables, indexes, etc, are stored in a single tablespace, with a maximum of two billion tables. ([Source](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?79,158,165))

Comment: MyISAM is the default storage engine for MySQL. Your tables are probably using MyISAM unless you explicitly stated to use InnoDB. Each MyISAM table is stored on disk in three files. The files have names that begin with the table name and have an extension to indicate the file type. An .frm file stores the table format. The data file has an .MYD extension. The index file has an .MYI extension. Further info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MyISAM.

Comment: +1 for still answering the question even after pointing out it's probably not a good idea.

Comment: A good example for this question is Wordpress Network.  Current version as of this comment (3.5) creates nine tables for every site.  For even a modest install that can be a lot of tables very quickly.

Comment: For what it's worth, I currently manage a Wordpress Multisite installation with about 7,000 sites in it.  That equates to 63,000 tables.  There are unique challenges with managing a large network like this, but it's certainly very possible.

Comment: @rinogo: I guess more than 65,535 works as well. If you still maintain that network of Wordpress sites, you're over that. And I bet there are unique challenges, hopefully you figured them out.

Comment: @rinogo WOW! Good job mate! I'm impressed.

Answer (score 7):

I also have a use case where a large number of tables is needed. At the moment one of our databases has close to 100.000 tables with excellent performance.

As Rob Guinness mentioned, there is a significant overhead for the .frm files. It's also important to note that any queries into information_schema without limitations on the schema and if possible the table itself will result in a serious performance hit while the query runs.

Comment: Does each of these tables have different structure?

Answer (score 6):

Contrary to Daniel Vassallo's answer, I have a use case where a large number of tables is needed. I could be wrong, but I don't think there is any "best practice" by which I could reduce the number of tables.

Although it is probably correct that the number of tables is only limited by the OS, I just want to add that I am using well over 1000 tables in a database with pretty good performance. The only downside seems to be increased overhead for the .frm files. In my case, I have split a very large table into 1000+ separate tables with the same table structure. MySQL partitioning was not an option for me because of denormalization, which requires 2 copies of each record in separate tables.

Comment: *"I have split a very large table into 1000+ separate tables "* - why did you have to do that?

Comment: To improve performance (faster query times). As I explained, partitioning was not an option because it doesn't allow me to put two copies of each record into different partitions (at least not any way I could figure out).

Comment: From a data normalization standpoint, many tables could be bad practice (depends on the tables). Just saying, each theory needs to be proven in practise and vice-versa. So I doubt the stance taken in your commentary (in the answer) but +1 for sharing what you did.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an official answer from MySql:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/database-count-limit.html

8.4.5 Limits on Number of Databases and Tables

MySQL has no limit on the number of databases. The underlying file system may have a limit on the number of directories.

MySQL has no limit on the number of tables. The underlying file system may have a limit on the number of files that represent tables. Individual storage engines may impose engine-specific constraints. InnoDB permits up to 4 billion tables.

Answer (score 3):

> The fact that you are asking this question is probably an indicator
>   that you are not taking a best practice approach to your problem.

One potential situation where you could need a lot of tables is when you are developing multi-tenant application where for each tenant you create separate set of tables (let's say with tentantId as a table name prefix). See this article (part Data Isolation): http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/11/architecting-a-multi-tenant-application.html