# The maximum number of tables in a single database

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Maximum Number of Tables in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137516/maximum-number-of-tables-in-mysql)

Is there a recommended number of tables a single database should contain. Also, is there any drawback in having more than one opened connection in your application.

The application I'm currently working on access a lot of tables or has the potential of accessing many tables. I thought of splitting the tables into different databases, since I have no experience with it, I hope someone will point me in the right direction.

Comment: Definitely a dupe & the answer to that question still holds - if you're concerned about having too many tables, you're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all Likelyhood the neccessity to split tables into seperate databases is best dealt with as need arises.

You say a lot of tables how many?  100, 200, 1000 - maybe the last one might possibly require seperate databases, but only if it had a definite advantage.

My suggestion would be that you look at why you need so many tables and in the first place, the likelyhood is you can do with less tables and more rows.

Comment: Less than a 100, but has the potential of reaching 100. I was worried because I had never hit such number before.

Comment: For what it's worth, I currently manage a Wordpress Multisite installation with about 7,000 sites in it. That equates to 63,000 tables. There are unique challenges with managing a large network like this, but it's certainly very possible.  Regardless, the advice is still sound - before adding more tables, you should consider if there's an alternative architecture that doesn't require so much database bloat.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MyISAM, the maximum number of tables is limited by the operating system/filesystem. It is the maximum number of files the OS allows in a directory, since the tables are stored as separate files on the filesystem.

For InnoDB, the limit appears to be [4 billion](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/118623).

There are pros and cons of having multiple open connections. What are you attempting to do? One thing to keep in mind is that there is a limit to the number of connections a MySQL server will accept.

Answer (score 1):

All queries in a single connection are serialized. This often makes programming simpler, especially if one command requires that the previous command completed. If you add more than one connection, you could end up with a race condition in the same situation.

Since MySQL doesn't support nested transactions, it's sometimes necessary to create another connection in order to complete a transaction within a transaction.