# maximum number of users

Tags: mysql

In order to limit user resources, I tend to create a new db user on each registration. The thing is, there can be millions of users signing up. And I have no idea about the maximum number of database users that can be created on MySQL.

How many users can be created on MySQL?

Comment: Creating millions of users seems like a bad idea in general. Are you sure your design is correct? The users are in the users table and I guess you could create that many, but it doesn't seem like a good idea on first sight.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137516/maximum-number-of-tables-in-mysql

This is a very useful link. Good answers on there.

Comment: @AnirudhRamanathan I have no idea. I just tend to limit db resources (queries per hour, updates per hour...) on each user instead of globally limiting them. Why is this a bad idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no hard coded limitations to number of users in a MySQL database. User accounts are stored in tables in terms of rows and columns that consume some variable amount of memory and disk space.  Although you could in theory add an infinite number of users, you will hit resource boundaries such as disk space, memory use, and processing time to add new users will take too long.

The exact limit depends on the configuration settings of the MySQL database.